# datetime.time() parameters not exists anymore?

Tags: python, datetime, typeerror

Yesterday I passed numbers to the hour and minute arguments of the `time` method (*lines 3 and 5*) without any problem, but today I got this error. I checked the documentation for `datetime.time`. I just can't understand what's going on. Why was it working yesterday but not today?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8068/3836677419.py in <module>
      1 # today=date.today()
      2 # print(today)
----> 3 start=datetime.time(hour=9)
      4 print(start)
      5 end=datetime.time(hour=17, minute=30)

TypeError: unbound method datetime.time() needs an argument
```

Comment: You have probably modified your import statement for datetime from *import datetime* to *from datetime import datetime*. That would cause this problem

Answer (score 2):

It entirely depends on how you import the `datetime` module in python. Note that the `datetime` module in python also has a `datetime` method. Don't get confused and use import the modules carefully.

If you want to directly import `datetime` module, the code will be

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
print(today)

start = datetime.time(hour=9)
print(start)
end = datetime.time(hour=17, minute=30)
print(end)


2022-07-24
09:00:00
17:30:00
```

Otherwise, Instead of importing the entire module, import the `date` and `time` methods you need

```
from datetime import date, time

today = date.today()
print(today)

start = time(hour=9)
print(start)

end = time(hour=17, minute=30)
print(end)

2022-07-24
09:00:00
17:30:00
```